# How to target a div with a same ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently have some ASP.Net code that builds an output and then displays it through a string literal. The idea is that for every `Receipt`, there is a 'view more' button which toggles extra information that is `display: none;` to start with. I tried to use the `eq()` method to attempt to find which one I wanted to toggle because I am doing that inside the `ul`. My current code is this:

```
$("#btn-expand").click(function () {
    var ldx = $("#list li .active").index(); // Get the list number so we know what ID to work with
    var idx = $("#expand").next().index(); // Get the next ID index point

    // Check that it isn't going negative
    if (idx == -1 || ldx == -1) {
        // If it is, reset ldx
        ldx = 0;
        idx = 0;
    }

    $("#expand").eq(ldx).toggle(); // Toggle that one
    console.log(ldx);
});
```

The first button works fine and `console.log` shows `0` however, all the others do not show anything. A sample of my HTML looks like this:

```
<ul id="list">
    <li class="active">
        Something <br />
        Something Again <br />
        <span id="btn-expand">[View more]</span>
        <div id="expand">
            Something hidden
        </div>
     </li>
     This <br />
     Shows <br />
     <span id="btn-expand">[View more]</span>
     <div id="expand">
         This is hidden until toggled
     </div>
     <li></li>
</ul>
```

There is a lot more `li` elements in the `ul` but that is how it is structured. I am also using `<span class="btn" id="btn-next">Next</span>` to loop through each `li` in the `ul` so I am really confused why the same method for doing it with the `#expand' won't work.

If anyone could point me in the right direction, I'd be appreciated. Thanks.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#btn-next").click(function() {
    var $list = $("#list li");
    var idx = $(".active").removeClass("active").next().index();
    if (idx == -1) {
      idx = 0;
    }
    $list.eq(idx).addClass("active");
  });

  $("#btn-prev").click(function() {
    var $list = $("#list li");
    var idx = $(".active").removeClass("active").prev().index();
    if (idx == -1) {
      idx = 0;
    }
    $list.eq(idx).addClass("active");
  });

  $("#btn-expand").click(function() {
    // Get the list number so we know what ID to work with
    var ldx = $("#list li .active").index();
    // Get the next ID index point
    var idx = $("#expand").next().index();
    // Check that it isn't going negative
    if (idx == -1 || ldx == -1) {
      // If it is, reset ldx
      ldx = 0;
      idx = 0;
    }
    // Toggle that one
    $("#expand").eq(ldx).toggle();
    console.log(ldx);
  });
});
```

```css
#list {
  list-style: none;
}
.active {
  display: block;
}
#btn-expand {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 9px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
#expand {
  display: none;
}
li {
  display: none;
}
.btn {
  background: none;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin-left: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list">
  <li class="active">
    Something here
    <br />Something here again
    <span id="btn-expand"> [View More] </span> 
    <br />
    <br />
    <span id="expand">
      This is hidden, shh..
    </span>
  </li>
  <li>
    You can see this
    <br />Toggling shouldn't effect me
    <span id="btn-expand"> [View More] </span> 
    <br />
    <br />
    <span id="expand">
      But toggling should effect me!
    </span>
  </li>
</ul>
<span class="btn" id="btn-prev">Prev</span> - <span class="btn" id="btn-next">Next</span>
```

Comment: you can't use `id` for multiple element, the `$('#expand')` selector will always select the first element with the same ìd`.

Comment: New to JavaScript, I'm more of a ASP/PHP developer. Thank-you for bringing that up however, I'll note that @ChihabJR

Comment: try to use `data-*` attribut instead of `id`

Comment: Is `active` intended to change also?

Comment: @charlietfl the active works on the `<li>` I only added that in-case it was causing some kind of interference with the code I was using. That is how I've done it on my side so I merely manipulated it because I cannot paste hard-code (sensitive data)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`id` should be unique in same document, replace the duplicate ones by general class, r.g :

```
<ul id="list">
   <li class="active">
      Something <br />
      Something Again <br />
      <span class="btn-expand">[View more]</span>
      <div class="expand">
         Something hidden
      </div>
   </li>
      This <br />
      Shows <br />
      <span class="btn-expand">[View more]</span>
      <div class="expand">
         This is hidden until toggled
      </div>
   <li>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Then replace id selector `#` in you script by class selector `.` :

```
$(".btn-expand").click(function() {
    // Get the list number so we know what ID to work with
    var ldx = $("#list li .active").index();
    // Get the next ID index point
    var idx = $(".expand").next().index();
    // Check that it isn't going negative
    if (idx == -1 || ldx == -1) {
      // If it is, reset ldx
      ldx = 0;
      idx = 0;
    }
    // Toggle that one
    $(".expand").eq(ldx).toggle();
    console.log(ldx);
});
```

You could use just `next()` instead of all the code in your event :

```
$(this).next(".expand").toggle();
//OR
$(this).next().toggle();
```

Hope this helps.

---

```js
$(".btn-expand").click(function() {
     $(this).next(".expand").toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list">
   <li class="active">
      Something <br />
      Something Again <br />
      <span class="btn-expand">[View more]</span>
      <div class="expand">
         Something hidden
      </div>
     
   </li>
   <li>
      This <br />
      Shows <br />
      <span class="btn-expand">[View more]</span>
      <div class="expand">
         This is hidden until toggled
      </div>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The first one works again but none of the others do @ZakariaAcharki :/ I changed `id=` to `class=` on them all and then in my JavaScript, changed the `#` to a `.` except the `#list` and only the first one toggles :/

Comment: None of that indexing is needed, just use `next()`

Comment: Could you edit the post and change it? @charlietfl Thank-you both!

Answer (score 1):

Change id's to classes and all you need then is:

```
$(".btn-expand").click(function() {
   $(this).next().toggle();
   $(this).text(function(_, oldText){
       return oldText.indexOf('More') === -1 ? 'View More' :'View Less';
   })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#btn-next").click(function() {
    var $list = $("#list li");
    var idx = $(".active").removeClass("active").next().index();
    if (idx == -1) {
      idx = 0;
    }
    $list.eq(idx).addClass("active");
  });

  $("#btn-prev").click(function() {
    var $list = $("#list li");
    var idx = $(".active").removeClass("active").prev().index();
    if (idx == -1) {
      idx = 0;
    }
    $list.eq(idx).addClass("active");
  });

  $(".btn-expand").click(function() {  
    // Toggle
    $(this).next().toggle();

  });
});
```

```css
#list {
  list-style: none;
}
.active {
  display: block;
}
#btn-expand {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 9px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

li {
  display: none;
}
.btn {
  background: none;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin-left: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.expand-inner {
display:inline-block;
width:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list">
  <li class="active">
    Something here
    <br />Something here again
    <span class="btn-expand"> [View More] </span>   
       <span style="display:none;">
      <div class="expand-inner">This is hidden, shh..</div>
      
    </span>
  </li>
  <li>
    You can see this
    <br />Toggling shouldn't effect me
    <span class="btn-expand"> [View More] </span>    
    <span style="display:none;">
        
      <div class="expand-inner">But toggling should effect me!</div>
    </span>
  </li>
</ul>
<span class="btn" id="btn-prev">Prev</span> - <span class="btn" id="btn-next">Next</span>
```